# IF Statement for Battery Level

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I'm working on a speech recognition program in C# and I've compiled a few lines of code that speaks back the current battery level when I say "battery level".

```
if (e.Result.Text.ToLower() == "battery level")
        {
            System.Management.ManagementClass wmi = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
            var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();
            String estimatedChargeRemaining = String.Empty;

            foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
            {
                estimatedChargeRemaining = Convert.ToString(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);
            }

            JARVIS.Speak("The Power Level Is At: " + estimatedChargeRemaining + "% sir");
            return;
        }
```

Within that I want to create *another* `if` statement to alert me if the battery level has dropped *below 25%*. How can this be done? I'm guessing it will be something like "`if estimatedChargeRemaining < 25 then JARVIS.Speak("Warning, Battery level has dropped below 25%")` but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what format `battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]` returns but it seems you can convert it to an int instead of a string.

```
int batteryLevel = Convert.ToInt32(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);
if(batteryLevel < 25)       
   JARVIS.Speak("Warning, Battery level has dropped below 25%");
```

You can then use that `batteryLevel` variable later on

```
JARVIS.Speak("The Power Level Is At: " + batteryLevel.ToString() + "% sir");
```

Not sure if it's intended but your `foreach` loop means that you'll only get the battery information of the last value in `allBatteries`. All the previous values will be overwritten.

Edit for comment (you should add error handling)

```
if (e.Result.Text.ToLower() == "battery level")
{
    System.Management.ManagementClass wmi = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
    var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();
    //String estimatedChargeRemaining = String.Empty;
    int batteryLevel = 0;

    foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
    {
        batteryLevel = Convert.ToInt32(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);
    }

    if(batteryLevel < 25)       
       JARVIS.Speak("Warning, Battery level has dropped below 25%");
    else //Guessing you want else
       JARVIS.Speak("The Power Level Is At: " + batteryLevel.ToString() + "% sir");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to how to layout the code? I'm getting "The name batteryLevel does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Updated the answer to show where to put the code. The reason you're getting that error is because you hadn't declared `int batteryLevel` before the loop. I just use `int batteryLevel` in the example to show that it was an int.

Comment: Ahh.. I get what has happened.. That code is only for if I say "battery level", It doesn't give me an automatic alert if the battery has dropped below 25% without me having to say "battery level". :(

Comment: You could have a timer that checks every 20 minutes (for example) and then call that code if the battery level is less than 25%.

Comment: Ah.. Yes.. That would be awesome! Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: See the timer example at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). You can put your battery checking code in the event handler.

Comment: I read `aTimer.Interval = 2000; aTimer.Enabled = true;` from the link you provided. Will I need a timer object in my form for this?

Comment: Yes, `aTimer` is a Timer object in the example.